# Website works fine in all browsers, except IE8

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

http://www.riddlecombe-manor.co.uk

This site works fine in all browsers except IE8! It uses the latest Wordpress installation and a custom theme. There is javascript and browser detection as well media detection in there (some of which is commented out as I don't want the site looking different on mobiles).

Anything anyone picks up on that looks like the cause of my headaches would be my friend forever!

Thanks all,

Cam

Comment: It would be helpful to know what happens in IE8.

Comment: You have to be more careful with IE than (*some*) other browsers, since Microsoft doesn't have all those standards that are being followed by (*some*) other browsers. In your case, what happens, if you run your project on IE8?

Comment: please state what isn't working. 'it doesn't work' is NOT helpful

Comment: Oh yeh - sorry... it just says "page-error" and shows a blank white page - I tested in Adobe Browserlab and it returns the same info (or lack thereof) "Page Error". Thanks for the rapid responses by the way!

Comment: Looks fine in IE8 to me no issues at all. IE7 throws an error relating to foundation.js but dosn't impair the functionality of the page.

Comment: Oh! What OS are you running IE8 on? I ran the site through Browsershots.org and it came up with the IE8 issues and then confirmed the problem with Adobe Browserlab... but you can't replicate the error? This problem just doesn't want to be fixed! Thanks again for all the help so far people :) I don't have access to run IE8 in debug mode as I'm running OSX...

Comment: Story of my life: "Website works fine in all browsers, except IE8"

Comment: When I take a look in Firefox with Firebug turned on I get three NetworkError:404 messages. Two are for CSS files (demo-style and jquery-sticklr-1.2...) and another for the jquery.mousewheel plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on script debugging in IE, you will see there is a javascript error happening on page load (related to 'foundation.js') that may be part of the problem:

```
SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: after 
foundation.js?ver=3.3.1, line 3 character 47347
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ran the site through Browsershots.org and it came up with the IE8 issues and then confirmed the problem with Adobe Browserlab... but you can't replicate the error? This problem just doesn't want to be fixed! I don't have access to run IE8 in debug mode as I'm running OSX...

Answer (score 1):

You've got 404s for a javascript and two style sheets. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or in Chrome or Safari or IE8, use the developer tools to see what's loading and not loading on your site.